# Isomoprhic and equal symbol for abelian groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two abelian groups and $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic. Moreover suppose that $A$ and $B$ are not the subgroups of the same group. Is it correct to write $A = B$? Thank you.

Comment: Definitely no. {}{}{}

Comment: @ Rubertos, Thank you. I was wondering, is there some situation where we can write equal?

Comment: When they are equal, meaning having the same elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely no. Even more, the collection of all groups isomorphic to an abelian group $G$ is a **proper class**.

Let $G$ an abelian group and $X$ be a set.

Then, you can define a natural operations on $G\times\{X\}$ so that $G\cong G\times \{X\}$. ( Define as $(g,X)(h,X)=(gh,X)$)

So for different two sets $X,Y$, $G\times \{X\}\cong G\times \{Y\}$, but they are obviously not equal.

Comment: @ Rubertos Thank you. I got it.

Comment: What has the fact that that an isomorphism class of groups is a proper class got to do with the legitimacy or truth of the assertion that $A = B$ for two particular groups?

Comment: @RobArthan I just wanted to emphasize that "set equality" is a completely different matter..

Answer (score 0):

You should **never**, **ever** claim the statement “$A=B$” is true unless $A$ is literally, *element-for-element*, the same thing as $B$...

... ***until*** you are mathematically experienced enough to abuse the notation $=$ responsibly.

Comment: While abuse of notation is fine in certain things, I hold that this is not one of them (but I didn't downvote).

Comment: Responsible use would at least require the groups to be *canonically* isomorphic, I suppose

Comment: @ Thank you Zev Chonoles. This makes sense.

Comment: $A = B$ is the assertion that $A$ and $B$ are equal. It is perfectly correct to use this expression when it is false, as in "Assume, for a contradiction that $A = B$, ..."

Comment: @Rob: Well, I don't disagree, though I feel it's *implied* that I only meant "saying the statement is true". Nevertheless I've edited.

Answer (score -1):

It is certainly correct to write $A = B$, in the same way that it is perfectly correct to write $1 = 2$. These are meaningful statements even if they are false.

That said, if you want to assert that $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic, then the standard notations are $A \simeq B$ or $A \stackrel{\sim}{=} B$ and not $A = B$.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: @ Thank you Rob Arthan. I got it (But the down vote not by me. )